# How to set a background-image without influencing other elements

Tags: html, css, background-image

I was wondering how you could set a background-image without changing the position of other elements? I would like to have that the items are on top of the bg-image.

(I've tried something with position: absolute but that made my other items unclickable and I took a random image because everything is offline)

Here's what I got:

```css
.bg-header{
  height: 77.5rem;
  width: 128.6rem;
  background-image: url(https://www.google.be/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjF0-TKlO_YAhVlIsAKHZQEA0wQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimagejournal.org%2F&psig=AOvVaw0k5kAcZwpSTzuIwHkdaVeO&ust=1516833850304522);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  
}


.container-header{
  width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
  <header>
  <div class="container-header">
        <div class="bg-header"></div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">activiteiten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">extra</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        
          <div class="title">
          <h1 class="blue">blue</h1>
          <div class="blok-title">
            <div class="M"></div>
            <h1 class="monday"><span class="hide">m</span>onday</h1>
          </div>
          <p class="intro">Het is ondertussen geen geheim meer. Maandagen zijn echt kutdagen. Maar als je er dan eentje moet uitkiezen die dan wel de ergste is, dan is het wel deze. </p>
        </div>
  
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Can you make the question any clearer? Which element's background-image are you trying to change?

Comment: Do you want the background to cover the entire body, or just the header?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your example to work you need `position: relative;` on `.container-header`, and this on `.bg-header`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-size: cover; /* Makes the image fill the element */
/* Remove height and width */
```

That will make the `.bg-header` take up the same area as `.container-header`. But you could also just apply the background image to `.container-header`and add

```
background-size: cover
```

To make the image fill the element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the background to appear behind all elements within your. In which case, you don't need the div with class bg-header. Simply apply the background to the header element or .container-header instead, like so:

```
.container-header {
    background-image: url(https://www.google.be/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwjF0-TKlO_YAhVlIsAKHZQEA0wQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimagejournal.org%2F&psig=AOvVaw0k5kAcZwpSTzuIwHkdaVeO&ust=1516833850304522); 
    width: 96rem; 
    margin: 0 auto;     
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Comment: But than i'm stuck with the width of 96 rem and it's bigger than that :/

Comment: I see. How large do you need it to be? Should it cover the entire page/body, or just the elements in the header, or something else?

Comment: Well it are actually some paint drops falling so yeah it almost takes in the full width

Comment: Full width of the page? Full height as well? It's starting to sound like you should just put the background on the body element.

Comment: No, it's not the full height. I'll put a screenshot in this link https://imgur.com/a/33J09

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? With `background-size: cover;` you can make the image stretch to fill the container, but keep its proportions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this  don't close the bg-header div tag and put a closing div tag '' right before your '' header closing tag